On Excel, how do I highlight a cell if the value inputted is not in my reference table?
I need help with conditional formatting on Excel.
I have two sheets, on Sheet1 I have 2 columns : Demand Planning Cluster and Region. On this sheet people are gonna input both DPC and Region.
Each Demand Planning Cluster has between 1 and 5 regions that are applicable. There are only 5 values to Region and around a 100 DPC. This is mapped in a table on Sheet2.
I want to highlight the region cell if the region value inputted is not linked to the Demand Planning Cluster on Sheet2.
I've written this formula and used it with conditional formatting rule :
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(C3, INDEX(sheet2!L63:P63, MATCH(B3, sheet2!$K$63:$K$156, 0),), 0)), TRUE, FALSE)
My region values are on columns L to P, and my DPC are on the column K.
The formula doesn't work for some reason, but I was also wondering how do I apply this rule to all the lines in the region column?
My reference table looks like 

Side note: the IF( and TRUE, FALSE) are redundant. One method of debugging conditional formatting is writing the formula in the sheet itself. What does it return there? You also likely need to think carefully about relative references like sheet2!L63:P63, which will be updated as the conditional formatting is applied down rows and across columns.

You have to define the whole range of Region, and on @BigBen comments use absolute references.
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(C3, INDEX(sheet2!$L$63:$P$156, MATCH(B3, sheet2!$K$63:$K$156, 0),), 0)), TRUE, FALSE)

What do you mean a whole range of Region? could you please give me an example?
For context, I have added a picture of what my reference table looks like, I didn't use absolute references because I want my formula to evaluate the specific regions for each DPC. Does that make sense?

Did you try the formula I posted? In the INDEX function the reference range is covering the Region.
